# How to Insert data from CSV file (Containing two columns Name & password) into table with variable table name in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, csv

Problem statement :-
How to Insert data from CSV file (Containing two columns Name & password) into table with variable table name depending upon first character in name field in MYSQL.

For eg, 
if Name is robert, then insert into table r_function. (depending upon first character in name field)
if name is susan, then insert into table s_function. (depending upon first character in name field)

I have a HUGE CSV file & I am using below query to insert data into table.
LOAD DATA INFILE 'abc.csv' INTO TABLE abc

How do I insert data when tablename is variable in a single query based on data in Name field?

Comment: To answer this, it is always a good idea to know how often you need to perform this process and what do you mean by **huge**. Now, f you are talking about table name being a **variable**, it would mean that you are running this within a peace of code (stored procedure/function/anonymous block). Which one is it? Also, why do you need the table name to be a variable?

Comment: I already have a framework in place. What I am trying to do is to optimize the current schema to minimiza time taken to upload CSV file data into database. I am using perl to do some manipulations and then insert data in DB. I have multiple tables a_function, b_functions . . . .  z_functions. 
'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.csv'  
INTO TABLE @TableName
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@Name, @Password)
SET Source=substring_index(@Name,'\/main',-1),@TableName=CONCAT(LEFT(Name,1),'_function');'

Comment: The issue is this is giving error as I am not sure it takes table name as a variable.Also I have 1000's of CSV to import into data base. The requirement is as such.